# Installing a netstandard package to .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget

The library [Google.Apis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis/) on NuGet claims the following:

> Supported Platforms:
>
> - .NET Framework 4.5+
> - NetStandard1.3, providing .NET Core support

However, the command `dotnet add package Google.Apis` tells me `error: Package 'Google.Apis' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '/home/pavel/[...]/api.csproj'.`.

Here is the csproj file being used:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
    <Folder Include="Utils\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

How do I install the package?

Comment: `dotnet new console` followed by `dotnet add package Google.Apis` works for me. To me that suggest that your `api.csproj` has an incompatible `TargetFramework`, just as the error message says. We need more information.

Comment: @zivkan I'm using netcoreapp2.2 as the target framework, which is also the default for `dotnet new console`, but I've included the csproj file in the question now.

Comment: try adding `<PackageReference Include="Google.Apis" Version="1.38.0" />` after the other `PackageReference`, then running `dotnet restore`. if that still fails adding `-v diag > restore.txt` to the end and attaching the restore log would help.

Comment: @zikvan Yep, it failed: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/7C4BI870VNSMXUgQHgpclg

Comment: The logs show you don't have any sources. Check your `nuget.config` to make sure it doesn't `<clear />` without adding a source. This is causing a different error to the one you originally reported above.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments to the question,  this was caused due to a `nuget.config` file that removed all sources. When I reproduced the scenario on my local machine, here's the full output:

```
  Writing /tmp/tmpd4dcSu.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'Google.Apis' into project '/home/zivkan/apiTest/apiTest.csproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for /home/zivkan/apiTest/apiTest.csproj...
error: Unable to resolve 'Google.Apis ' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1'.
error: Package 'Google.Apis' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project '/home/zivkan/apiTest/apiTest.csproj'.
```

The second error message, the one you reported in your question, is very misleading. However, the first error message "Unable to resolve" gives a good hint that NuGet is unable to find the package.